# How to disable this three finger gesture for redo/undo? (iPadOS 16)

Tags: ipad, ipados, gesture, undo-redo

Already did a bit of research but couldn't find any proper guide to disable this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is under the Multitasking & Gestures section of Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't disable three fingers gestures but you can use AssistiveTouch. Please Go to Settings > Accessibility > Touch > AssistiveTouch, then turn on AssistiveTouch. Then you see a button appear onscreen and You can drag the button to any edge of the screen.

Comment: How will AssistiveTouch solve the aforementioned issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can disable that function by enabling another that does the same action.

This is probably not the best solution but it works and I don't think there's other options.

Go to Settings > Accessibility > Touch and enable "Shake to Undo". It will simple ignore the three-finger gesture to undo.

[image]

This works for me, I am on iPadOS 16.2.

Comment: Shake to Undo has nothing to do with the 3 finger touch gesture.  I just verified this on iPadOS 16 and the Notes App.  With shake disabled, the three finger gesture still executes an Undo action.  How did you test?  What does your exact gesture look like?

Comment: @Allan I tried swiping either side of the screen with 3 fingers and it did not work, idk if it's the right way to do this. I have also shaked my iPad and it does undo.

Comment: If you disable “Shake to Undo” you should expect it to not undo.  Since the Undo “icon” is a curved left pointing arrow, try moving your fingers such that they form three dots vertically, then swipe from the right to the left.  Before disabling anything, make sure you have the function working first because if you don’t know this, you’ll never know if your “fix” was successful.

Comment: @Allan I have just checked, thank you for explaining, I was mistaken.

Comment: Going forward, you need to remember to be able to **reproduce the issue** before you can solve it.

Comment: @Allan Yes, you're right, sorry